# Select an element by data attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to select element by its data attribute using jQuery?
I have a div

```
<div class="remove">delete</div>
```

And I've added data attributes to it like so:

```
$('.remove').attr('data-id', data._id);
$('.remove').attr('data-rev', data._rev);
```

What I want is to select this element based on its `'data-id'` and `'data-rev'` using jQuery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like

```
$('.remove[data-id = "' + data._id + '"]');
$('.remove[data-rev = "' + data._rev + '"]');
```

If you want to check both the `data` then you can use

```
$('.remove[data-id = "' + data._id + '"][data-rev = "' + data._rev + '"]');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('.remove[data-id = "' + data_id + '"][data-rev = "' + data_rev + '"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.remove[data-id="'+data._id+'"]');
$('.remove[data-rev="'+data._rev+'"]');
```

reference **[attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try [attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('.remove[data-id="'+data._id+'"]')
$('.remove[data-rev="'+data._rev+'"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var $dataId = $('.remove').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('id') === 'something';
});

var $dataRev = $('.remove').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('rev') === 'something';
});
```

and then you can use the variables like:

```
$dataId.show();
$dataRev.hide();
```